# I executed the following program but i m confused about its output?

Tags: linux, fork

I am confused about the no of child process it is creating on execution

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
int i=0;
fork();
fork();
fork();
fork();
pid_t pid;
    if((pid=fork()) == 0) { 
        printf("I am the child: %u\n", getpid());
}
    else {
        printf("I am the parent: %u and my child is: %u\n", getpid(),pid);
    }

return 0;
}
```

can somebody help me in understanding that why there are so many child process and why parent id is different every time.

The output I get is :

```
saqlain@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ gcc -c fork.c
saqlain@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ gcc -o fork fork.c
saqlain@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ ./fork
I am the parent: 11842 and my child is: 11847
saqlain@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ I am the child: 11847
I am the child: 11849
I am the parent: 11846 and my child is: 11850
I am the child: 11867
I am the child: 11869
I am the parent: 11843 and my child is: 11856
I am the child: 11850
I am the parent: 11848 and my child is: 11857
I am the parent: 11852 and my child is: 11860
I am the parent: 11845 and my child is: 11849
I am the parent: 11854 and my child is: 11866
I am the child: 11859
I am the child: 11856
I am the child: 11857
I am the parent: 11862 and my child is: 11869
I am the parent: 11865 and my child is: 11870
I am the child: 11860
I am the child: 11866
I am the parent: 11855 and my child is: 11867
I am the parent: 11851 and my child is: 11859
I am the parent: 11863 and my child is: 11871
I am the parent: 11858 and my child is: 11872
I am the parent: 11868 and my child is: 11873
I am the parent: 11844 and my child is: 11861
I am the child: 11870
I am the child: 11861
I am the child: 11864
I am the child: 11872
I am the child: 11871
I am the child: 11873
I am the parent: 11853 and my child is: 11864
```

Answer (score 1):

You're executing `fork` 5 times, and on the fifth, printing output.

Each `fork` splits control into two identical copies, so 2×2×2×2×2 = 32 copies, of which, 16 each identify as parents and children based upon the fifth and final `fork`.